# How to log a warning without creating a logger?

Tags: python, logging

How does one log a warning without creating a logger python? I also want to make sure it DOES log properly.

Is:

```
import logging
logging.warning('warning')
```

enough?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by _properly_ and _enough_. Have you tried it to see if it fits your needs? What are your concerns?

Comment: you might find the built-in [warning](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) useful

Comment: consider doing: `import logging` then `logging.warning(f'warning with real information from your code')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes:

```
import logging
logging.warning('warning with real information from your code')
```

ouput:

```
WARNING:root:warning
```

Comment: Not sure if this will help anyone anyway. But I would suggest logging *anything* other than `'warning'` (and `'root'`) to differentiate clearly between the different warning words in input and output, e.g. `'this is a warning'`.

Comment: @luk2302 agreed `logging.warning('warning with real information from your code')` edited.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you want logging without all the hassle with setting up a logger. If you don't mind installing third-party package, have a look at [loguru](https://pypi.org/project/loguru/).
It is [ready to use out of the box](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru#ready-to-use-out-of-the-box-without-boilerplate) without boilerplate:

```
from loguru import logger

logger.warning("That's it, beautiful and simple logging!")
```

Check the docs for more info.

Comment: nice! Though, installing dependencies is usually nasty cuz logouru will bring it's own dependencies and screw up your code, but nice answer regardless.

Comment: There are minimal dependencies and depending on the platform and python version, there might be no dependencies at all. check [install_requires](https://github.com/Delgan/loguru/blob/3d5234541c81318e7f6f725eca7bab294fe09c23/setup.py#L51)